# Gym env.render() kernel crashes

Tags: python, crash, render, openai-gym

I have a conda env with python 3.10.6 and gym==0.26.0

I open a new ipynb in my vscode and run

```
import gym
```

```
env = gym.make('CarRacing-v2') # i tried more envs from classic control and box2d and all have the same issue
```

and now when I run this it works and all 3 numbers are printed

```
observation = env.reset()
for _ in range(100):
    print(-1)
    state, reward, terminated, _, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    print(0)
    # env.render()
    print(1)
```

but when I uncomment the env.render() the kernel crashes with this message:

*The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done*

it looks like an issue with env render. I tried reinstalling gym and all its dependencies but it didnt help. I tried making a new conda env and installing gym there and same problem...

I tried making a normal .py file and this happened

```
import gym
env = gym.make("CarRacing-v2", render_mode="human")
observation, info = env.reset()
```

When I run this I get this error
`libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri) libGL error: failed to load driver: iris libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri) libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX) Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext) Value in failed request:  0x0 Serial number of failed request:  101 Current serial number in output stream:  102`

but when i remove the render_mode, there is no error. And when I let the render_mode as human but remove env.reset() there is also no error.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

i had your problem too and i did these steps and it worked for me.
first i update my *vs-code IDE*

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install code
```

after that i removed my gym library and installed *gym=0.21* using *pip*. i don't know why but this version work properly.

```
pip install gym==0.21
```

note: if you don't have pip, you can install it according to this [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/).

And then reopened my IDE using *ctrl+shift+p* buttons and *reload window* and run the cell again and env.render() worked this time.

Answer (score 0):

This is common for using old version openai gym on headless server. The solution is simple. I only tested it with my OpenGL backend=osmesa. But I think it works for EGL as well. Anyway, you can always switch to osmesa.

Basically, in Ubuntu22.04, you will have a `swrast_dri.so` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/`. So we can just create a symbol link to it:

```bash
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/dri
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
```

This is for `swrast_dri.so`. For `iris_dri.so`, I guess the solution is the same. My solution is copied from [here](https://forum.step.esa.int/t/snap9-error-libegl-warning-mesa-loader-failed-to-open-swrast/36702/5).